# How to use Docker Volumes?

Tags: django, docker, devops

I am completely new to Docker, right now I am using an open-source tool, which is a Docker application, I need to make some changes to the existing application for my requirement and it should reflect the changes, I did a lot of searching, then I found that we can do this with the help of **Docker Volumes**, but I am unable to follow any of the articles on the web as well as documentation? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  cvat_db:
    container_name: cvat_db
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_DB: cvat
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    volumes:
      - cvat_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  cvat_redis:
    container_name: cvat_redis
    image: redis:4.0-alpine
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - redis
    restart: always

  cvat:
    container_name: cvat
    image: cvat/server
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - cvat_redis
      - cvat_db
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        http_proxy:
        https_proxy:
        no_proxy: nuclio,${no_proxy}
        socks_proxy:
        USER: "django"
        DJANGO_CONFIGURATION: "production"
        TZ: "Etc/UTC"
        CLAM_AV: "no"
    environment:
      DJANGO_MODWSGI_EXTRA_ARGS: ""
      ALLOWED_HOSTS: '*'
      CVAT_REDIS_HOST: "cvat_redis"
      CVAT_POSTGRES_HOST: "cvat_db"
    volumes:
      - cvat_data:/home/django/data
      - cvat_keys:/home/django/keys
      - cvat_logs:/home/django/logs
      - cvat_models:/home/django/models

  cvat_ui:
    container_name: cvat_ui
    image: cvat/ui
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        http_proxy:
        https_proxy:
        no_proxy:
        socks_proxy:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ui

    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ui
    depends_on:
      - cvat

  cvat_proxy:
    container_name: cvat_proxy
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - cvat
      - cvat_ui
    environment:
      CVAT_HOST: localhost
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./cvat_proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./cvat_proxy/conf.d/cvat.conf.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/cvat.conf.template:ro
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '$$CVAT_HOST' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/cvat.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/24

volumes:
  cvat_db:
  cvat_data:
  cvat_keys:
  cvat_logs:
  cvat_models:
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker volumes are mostly used as a way to save data outside of your container. If you mount a volume and store data in it, the data will not be erased when the container is destroyed. In order to mount a volume, you have to add `-v <directory in your machine>:<directory in your container>` to your `docker run` command. It may fulfill your requirements, but it most likely wont be enough.

If your assignment requires you to change for instance the behaviour of the application, then you have to rebuild the docker image and use it in your *docker-compose.yml*

Comment: <directory in your container>, do you mean, the volume or the container name?